# Resize container view iOS 8 swift based on the device

Tags: ios, swift, containers

I am a newbie to the iOS development and I am trying to create a table view with multiple sections with a container view controller, embedding a table view, as you can see in the picture attached in this post.

I am having problem resizing the container view to fit properly the available space; I would like, that based on the device I'm running the app on, the container view could calculate it's height dynamically.
In the picture I have attached there are two red sticks to show the desired height of the container view at runtime.

The solution I tried to implement is the following one:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    contView.frame.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height - CGFloat(contView.frame.origin.y)
}
```

The height of the container view is the difference between the `bounds.size.height` of the view and the `frame.origin.y` of the container view.
That pretty much solved my problem but I would like your assistance to figure out if there is a clever and smarter way to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance for your kindness and patience.

Comment: I don't see any picture regarding your issue. Can you post it?

Comment: You can use UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size or UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.origin. It will give you values depending on device sizes.

Comment: unfortunately it won't me allow to post any image because my reputation is  less than 10.

Comment: Any idea how can I share this photo with you so I can show what my doubt is? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can "play" with coordinates like that to understand some key concepts, but in a real app you should better use auto layout constraints which be more efficient.
have you tried to follow a tutorial like this one ? http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You could use auto layout size classes. So you are able to adopt your layout for different screen sizes.Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1